# How to install Subversion client on Eclipse without using eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse

I want to access Subversion server using client plugin in eclipse. However I dont have plugin installed in Eclipse.

In my  network its not allowed to access eclipse marketplace and install the plugin.

Is there any alternative way to install the subversion client in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

you can get easily through official website
Link :https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

Answer (score 1):

## 2 steps:

### Step 1, get the SVN plugin

Download it from http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Or, copy from your fellows' computer. As you said

> I am not able to get any download version of subversion plugin.

### Step 2, install

Unzip it. The file name may like **site-1.6.18** , it depends on what you downlaoded or copied.

Copy the file to **%ECLIPSE_HOME%/dropins/** , then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can.
Download Subversion plugn. Unzip it and copy plugin jar in plugin folder of  your Eclipse home.
If there is any features stuff in unzip file copy that too in features folder of your eclipe home. and restart eclipse. It should work.

Comment: Link given by @User3208908 have downloads for latest as well as for previous version of ecplse. I am pasting same here again.

Comment: sorry forgot it copy link.:https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

Answer (score 0):

Download the connector from [Subsversive 5.0](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/5.0/builds/).
Then in Eclipse go to: Help/Install new software/Add/Archive and select the zip file you just downloaded. Select the features you need, uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software", anche click Finish.

Job done.

Cheers.